# polars stuck in right transformations

Tags: python-polars

```
import polars as pl

data = {
    'section': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'name': ['Tam', 'Danny', 'David', 'Bokres', 'Helli', 'Jacky', 'Telli', 'Nam', 'Luo'],
    'age': [19, 20, 21, 22, 22, 34, 21, 19, 21],
    'BMI': [22, 22, 19, 22, 22, 24, 22, 22, 23]
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)
```

I wish to transform above dataframe to below dict: (Essentially the key is section name, with value has Total and Filtered count and the Details is basically each row of dataframe as form of list)

```
Expected Output:
{'A': {'Total': 5, 'Filtered': 0, 'Details': [['A', 'Tam', 19, 22], ......]},
             'B': {'Total': 4, 'Filtered': 2, 'Details': [['B', 'Jacky', 34, 24], ......]}}
```

Tried:

```
df.groupby('section').agg(pl.count().alias('Total'),
                          pl.col('name').filter(pl.col('BMI') > 22.5).count().alias('Filtered')).join(df, how='left', on='section')

df.groupby('section').agg(pl.col('section', 'name', 'age', 'BMI'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for `.rows_by_key`

**Edit:** You can add a copy of the section column to include in the Details values.

```
(df.with_columns(
    pl.col('section').suffix('_copy'),
    Total    = pl.count().over('section'),
    Filtered = pl.col('name').filter(pl.col('BMI') > 22.5).count().over('section'),
 )
 .select(pl.col('section_copy'), pl.exclude('section_copy'))
 .rows_by_key(['section', 'Total', 'Filtered'])
)
```

```
defaultdict(list,
            {('A', 5, 0): [('A', 'Tam', 19, 22),
              ('A', 'Danny', 20, 22),
              ('A', 'David', 21, 19),
              ('A', 'Bokres', 22, 22),
              ('A', 'Helli', 22, 22)],
             ('B', 4, 2): [('B', 'Jacky', 34, 24),
              ('B', 'Telli', 21, 22),
              ('B', 'Nam', 19, 22),
              ('B', 'Luo', 21, 23)]})
```

You could then turn the resulting tuple keys into the dict structure you desire.

Comment: This essentially miss the section name in the value/list if you see, for example: ('Tam', 19, 22), I want to have section in this as well in this which is possible if I duplicate the section entry as a separate column.

Comment: Pass `include_key=True` to `.rows_by_key` - although this adds the others. You could add the section in when turning the tuple keys into dicts I suppose.

Comment: Won't that include Total and Filtered as well and not just section? I am getting AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rows_by_key' so figuring that out for now.

Comment: Yes, it will. If you want just the section you could make a copy of the column instead. You need `>= 0.18.5` for `.rows_by_key`

Comment: Got it thanks. Any reason why we get list of tuples, instead of list of list in the output above?

Comment: I think returning tuples is some "API standard" e.g. like the `.fetch*()` methods of the `sqlite3` module (and others)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254411/discussion-between-r-ram-and-jqurious).